# How to get an integer on selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I got this page where I want to run my code:

I got a css with this properties:

```
<center>

    Radicacion Exitosa, Numero Radicacion: 12 - 132263…

</center>
```

I want to store the "132263" in a variable because I have to copy and paste them in another window, so I want to know if there is a way to only get the number from that tag...specially the "132263" because if I store a Variable Selenium IDE only will get the full text.

Thanks

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to switch to Selenium Webdriver for such testing. Much easier to handle real complicated scenarios

Comment: @Saifur Thanks for your recomendation but I couldn't switch to it because the test are very simple but sometimes I find things like this where I can't evade them

Comment: Please, stop suggesting switching to webdriver every time someone has a difficult question in selenium IDE, it's non productive. and in this case is over kill for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex in javascript will do this for you:

```
<tr>
<td>storeText</td>
<td>//center</td>
<td>full</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>var regex=/\-\s+(\d+)\s+\-/;regex.exec(storedVars['full'])[1];</td>
<td>number</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${number}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

We're capturing the text from the CENTER tag and then running the regex to grab the number out of it (using the group (\d+) and returning [1]).

Comment: THANKS!!!! It worked, but can you explain me what will do

var regex=/\-\s+(\d+)\s+\-/;regex.exec(storedVars['full'])[1];

Comment: Sure, that's just a regular expression designed to match on "- 123456 -" and uses regex group to return just the \d+ (123456) portion.